# SQL How can SELECT "CASE WHEN" with exactly opposite conditions, but neither are selected?

Tags: sql

With the following SQL SELECT:

```
WITH cte AS (

    SELECT  Title DBUser_Title, 
            GP_JobTitle GP_Title, 
            DESC_ AIMS_Title
    FROM ScheduleTable
)

SELECT  *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN AIMS_Title = DBUser_Title THEN 'IsEqual' 
        END AIMS_equals_DBUser,

    CASE 
        WHEN AIMS_Title <> null AND AIMS_Title = 'Lead XX' and AIMS_Title != DBUser_Title THEN AIMS_Title
        WHEN AIMS_Title <> null AND AIMS_Title = 'Lead XX' and AIMS_Title =  DBUser_Title THEN AIMS_Title
    END SELECTED_Title

FROM cte
```

The results of this query have SELECTED_Title = NULL in all cases.

[image]

How is this possible?

(Sorry for the obfuscation.  My company is paranoid about PII.  To them, your shoelace length might *out* you.  I added the "IsEqual" select so you can be sure.)

Comment: Because `WHEN AIMS_Title <> null` is not how you express "is not null", weirdly it should be `WHEN AIMS_Title is not null`...

Comment: SQL NULL is not a value , it's a way to show that value is unknown. Any expression using operators with NULL will always yield NULL therefore your result set of query above will always have NULL in SELECTED_Title column. More about nulls here https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-null-values/amp/

Comment: @Stu.  Well, dang.  That worked fine.  If you make that an "answer", I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since NULLs represent an unknown quantity or value, you cannot equate anything to NULL, not even another NULL; comparing a known value to an unknown value always results in an unknown value.

To correctly check NULL values you have to use the specific syntax `is null` or `is not null`.

Comment: I especially like the statement: "comparing a known value to an unknown value always results in an unknown value"  it's not true, it's not false, it's unknown!